# centering 3 columns inside a panel body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a panel body that contains 3 columns that span 5/12 of the bootstrap's grid system. I am trying to center these columns but using `text-center` and `center-block` have not been successful for me. The following is my panel setup (generalized).

[image]

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Panel Title</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div>
                <label>Label</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <select id="id" size="8" style="width: 99%;">
                                            <option>
                        potato
                    </option>
                                          <option>
                        potato
                    </option>
                                          <option>
                        potato
                    </option>
                                          <option>
                        potato
                    </option>
                                          <option>
                        potato
                    </option>
                                          <option>
                        potato
                    </option>
                                          <option>
                        potato
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a class="btn btn-primary">click</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top: 3%;">
            <div>
                <a class="btn btn-primary">
                    All →</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a class="btn btn-primary">
                    All ←</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div>
                <label>Label</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <select id="id2" size="8" style="width: 99%">
                    <option>
                        potato
                    </option>
                                          <option>
                        potato
                    </option>
                                          <option>
                        potato
                    </option>
                                          <option>
                        potato
                    </option>
                                          <option>
                        potato
                    </option>
                                          <option>
                        potato
                    </option>

                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a working example - stripped down but working](http://www.bootply.com/a3Vkvt8rtp)

Comment: like this? http://www.bootply.com/dmKY5DhGwh

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith i started with that method as well, but the content is pushed slightly too far to use that.

Comment: I see, what about this? https://jsfiddle.net/c259LrpL/

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I think its working only in `lg'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.col-xs-5ths,
.col-sm-5ths,
.col-md-5ths,
.col-lg-5ths {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.col-xs-5ths {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-5ths {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-5ths {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-lg-5ths {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Panel Title</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body bodyy">
          <div class="col-md-5ths"></div>
          <div class="col-md-5ths">
            <div>
              <label>Label</label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <select id="id" size="8" style="width: 99%;">
                <option ng-repeat="thing in things">
                  {{thing}}
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="click()">click</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5ths text-center" style="margin-top: 3%;">
            <div>
              <a class="btn btn-primary"
                 ng-click="click('woo')">
                All &rarr;</a>
            </div>
            <div>
              <a class="btn btn-primary"
                 ng-click="clicky('wooo')">
                All &larr;</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5ths">
            <div>
              <label>Label</label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <select id="id2" size="8" style="width: 99%">
                <option ng-repeat="stuff in stuffs">
                  {{stuff}}
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You should add the Bootstrap latest CSS, it should work fine here at my end if am adding the bootstrap css file. Updated answer check now, or [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zeasts/0ggoy5w7/)

Comment: updated answer looks like it is working - will these media queries mess up other parts of my application though?

Comment: Using media queries one can do miracle designs @Jordan.J.D

Comment: Can you explain media queries to center different numbers of columns in a panel (how would your code be edited for different # of columns)

Comment: @Jordan.J.D,  You need the centre the columns in a panel using CSS ?

Comment: I fixed up what I needed. Thanks I accepted your answer.

Answer (score -1):

For the `div` that wraps the `<a class="btn btn-primary">`, if you gave this a class you could apply, e.g. `margin-left: -7px;`

That fixed it for me in your test tool.

Comment: i don't see any change in the bootply trying this. can you fork the bootply and show your working example?